# C++ Sudoku Solver File Redirection

Tags: c++

What I am trying to do is read in a 9x9 grid with numbers using file redirection and just reprint that same file but whenever I run the ./app.out  Sudoku1.out it either prints nothing to the .out file or what appears to be a bunch of pointers to data locations. We can't use file i/o so my instructions say: all data can be obtained by the way of the stdin prompt interactively. You can then feed the data to your program from a file by using file redirection. I feel like I am overlooking the simplest thing any help would be appreciated. Here is my Sudoku1.in file (a 0 means a blank spot):

```
0 0 5 7 1 0 6 8 2
0 3 6 0 4 0 0 7 5
7 0 0 5 8 6 3 4 9
9 8 4 0 5 7 2 0 0
1 5 0 0 0 0 7 9 8
6 7 2 8 0 0 0 0 4
0 6 8 2 0 9 0 1 0
3 4 9 1 0 0 8 2 0
0 1 7 0 3 0 9 0 6
```

Here is my Sudoku.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mySudoku.h"

using namespace std;

mySudoku::mySudoku(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++){
            Data[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

mySudoku::mySudoku(int anArray[][Size]){
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++){
            Data[i][j] = anArray[i][j];
        }
    }
}

mySudoku::mySudoku(const mySudoku& orig){

}

mySudoku::~mySudoku(){

}

void mySudoku::ReadPuzzle(){

}

void mySudoku::PrintPuzzle(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++){
            cout << Data[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


bool mySudoku::CheckRow(int row, int number){

}

bool mySudoku::CheckCol(int col, int number){

}
```

Here is my mySudoku.h file:

```
#ifndef MYSUDOKU_H
#define MYSUDOKU_H

const int Size(9);

class mySudoku {
public:
    mySudoku();
    mySudoku(int anArray[][Size]);
    mySudoku(const mySudoku& orig);

    void ReadPuzzle();
    void PrintPuzzle();
    bool CheckRow(int row, int number);
    bool CheckCol(int col, int number);
    virtual ~mySudoku();
private:
    int Data[Size][Size];
};

#endif  /* MYSUDOKU_H */
```

Comment: when you say "./app.out Sudoku1.out" do you acutally mean "cat Sudoku1.in | app.out Sudoku1.out"? Because you have to actually do the file redirection

Comment: Nevermind I got it. Sorry for posting

Answer (score 0):

In order to read data from `stdin`, you should use `std::cin` and then test you program in the following way:

```
cat Sudoku1.in | ./app.out
```

Right now I do not see any function that does this in your file, though you haven't added the `main()` function. You can edit your `ReadPuzzle()` method though, in the following way:

```
void mySudoku::ReadPuzzle() {
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
            cin >> Data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it inside `main()`

```
int main() {
  mySudoku ms;
  ms.readPuzzle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to read puzzle from `cin` in the same way you are printing it:

```
void mySudoku::ReadPuzzle(){
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < Size; j++){
            cin >> Data[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can enter input in console or redirect it from text file using pipe `cat Sudoku1.in | ./app.out`